# How to convert android existing app to react-native android

Tags: java, android, react-native, native

I have developed an android app with code, i want to convert to react native android. is this possible to convert an existing android app to react native?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React Native is a JS based layer programming provided by FB. If you want to convert the existing android app into RN then you need to create a separate project in RN using node and have to change your Activity or Fragment views design into RN Js components and for functionality you have to create a bridge module so that communication would be establish in between RN JS Components and Android native code.

There is library that would help to make from native to react native using library [react native brownfield](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-brownfield), this library will help to make bridging your native app with react native.

Comment: Yes. If I will suggest you then you should create it by scratch so it will work for both technologies Android and iOS

Comment: but there must be a detailed tutorial for beginners