# Can you export a Flutter project to Java & Swift?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have been working with [Flutter](https://flutter.io) for some time and have a functioning app that works just fine.

What I am trying to do is *'export'* my Flutter project into native Android / Java to give to the Android developer and Swift / Objective-C to give to the iOS developer for further changes and customization.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50678486/2480714) discusses the import functionality, but with regards to export is this something that can be done? Does Flutter have such an operation?

Comment: I added another link at the top of the list (better than the others)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed a Flutter app as view to Java and iOS, but you can not convert it to Java, Kotlin, Swift or Object-C

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps
- https://docs.flutter.io/javadoc/io/flutter/view/FlutterView.html
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_view

This example might also be related

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_view