# Flutter - Am I able to creat a module with Flutter and use it in my iOS and Android projects?

Tags: flutter

In my company, we are working on a huge product. We have a repo for the Android project and also we have another repo for the iOS project.

I think it is impossible to rewrite the whole of the project in Flutter. So, something that popped in my mind but I am not sure if it is feasible. Each Android/iOS project contains many modules. I am working on a module called Enterprise. It has its own Activities, Fragments and business logic. So, my question is, Am I able to consider this module as a black box (it has a few inputs that are coming from the other modules and a few outputs that will be presented in the app module) and make it by Flutter. Then I will use its .aar version in the Android project as well as the iOS project.

Does an implementation like this is feasible?

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting the vote to close this question. The question has enough details and nothing about it is optional. This is similar to this question that has not received the vote to be closed, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49461746/513413.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found Flutter is thinking of a way to solve this issue. I found two links that might be useful to you, too:

1. A[dd Flutter to existing apps](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps). According to this page, "The "add-to-app" support is in preview, and is so far only available on the master channel.".
2. [Integrating Flutter into an Existing App](https://medium.com/@tpolansk/integrating-flutter-into-an-existing-app-part-one-flutter-with-submodules-9b633ff3cf10).

I will be more than happy to accept your answer if you have a better approach.