# How Add Flutter To Existing Or New Android App

Tags: java, android, flutter

Suppose I have a large existing native android application written in java. And now I have decided to make this application cross-platform using flutter technology. I know that I can implement flutter and rewrite the project on this technology in parts, but can I, for example, make a cross-platform activity on flutter and put native java code inside it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461746/flutter-import-from-existing-android-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't anything to convert and android native app to flutter but if you want your existing android application cross-platform you can use kotlin to make it hybrid https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/